# Is the "ocws.officeapps.live.com" API used by the Office 365 start page open for re-use?

Tags: office-365, office-web-apps, office-365-developer, office365apis

The Office 365 start page shows a list of recently used documents.

The data is being fetched from https://ocws.officeapps.live.com/ocs/v2/recent/docs?apps=Word,Excel,PowerPoint,Visio,OneNote,Sway&show=100&rs=en-US

Is this an official API that we can use? Where can I find documentation or an SDK around it?

(Note: there is another question about how to get these documents [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223698/any-apis-to-get-last-opened-documents). I know about the Microsoft Graph endpoints, but this question is specifically about above API.)

Comment: Having the same issue. We were able to reproduce the call, however we need to know how to get the **authorization: `Bearer hshshshshsshshshshsh`** string required in the headers for the GET call.