# Which "recently used documents" API should I use?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-graph

I need to get the recently used documents of the user, focus being on SharePoint and OneDrive documents and the Microsoft Graph.

There are two potential endpoints:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_recent

> List a set of items that have been recently used by the signed in user

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/insights_list_used

> Calculated relationship identifying documents viewed and modified by a user.

Which one should I use and why? Why not the other? Other endpoints?

(Note that there is another potential candidate outside the Microsoft Graph - I am asking for this [over here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243534/is-the-ocws-officeapps-live-com-api-used-by-the-office-365-start-page-open-for). And let's ignore the fact that one API is still in preview/beta.)

Answer (score 0):

You should used below end point for production

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_recent
```

because the beta endpoint includes APIs that are currently in preview and are not yet generally available. The APIs in the beta endpoint are subject to change. So Microsoft don't recommend that you use them in your production apps..

For more details, [refer this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/beta-overview)

Comment: Let's assume the APIs were all in production. How would your answer look in this case?

Comment: Hey @HeinrichUlbricht, I have updated my answer you can check reference  link you will get idea.